# String manipulation - c# and gmail

Tags: c#, gmail

I have tried to do some research, but everything that I find does not cover what my current dilemma is.

String manipulation is basic right? But here is my problem, I am grabbing an email body from gmail, the body looks something like this (after removing all the HTML formatting, and is a constant string):
Name : Testy Von Test
Cell    1111111111
email   testy@testy

Now I need to find the string "Name" and then use trimming to get the full name, but how do I distinguish between this? how do I tell my coding to look for everything from name until Cell and take everything from there? I really did try to find the solution as I believe I am just missing some logic in my mind. If you just give me a link to an article I will be happy to read up and apply the logic myself (I am not expecting anyone to do my work for me), I just need a proper nudge in the right direction please.

Thank you kindly in advance.

(as an edit if anyone should follow this question, look at all the answers, there are a bunch of amazing answers and ideas)

Comment: Will your email body always have the name followed by numeric characters? like "Testy Von Test Cell" followed by "1111111111" ?

Comment: Have you tried `String.IndexOf`?

Comment: If you are feeling strong with regex, this would be a solution to your problem. Here is an example: http://www.dotnetperls.com/regex-match.

Comment: As far as I have tested, yes.

Comment: okay looking into regex example now, going to run a few test apps and see how regex and string.Indexof will work. Thanks for all the help and fast responses.

Comment: HimBromBeere, the substrings ended up being the best solution thus far. Pawel Mach, thank you kindly for your link, it was good material for me to work through. Thank you all kindly for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The string you have doesn't seem very well formatted.  Name is followed by a colon, Cell is not... this could get very tricky...

but a simple solution using substring.

```
var s = "Name : Testy Von Test Cell 1111111111 email testy@testy";
var name = s.Substring(
    s.IndexOf(":")+1,
    s.IndexOf("Cell")-s.IndexOf(":")-1);
```

Comment: it is indeed tricky, I at times have had it with " * " instead of a colon or couple of spaces, but I figured removing the * and odd formatting should be simple, after I have my values. Thank you kindly I am applying your answer and researching the comments solution at the moment, will get back to you once i have a solution. Thank you kindly for your assistance, I sincerely appreciate it.

Comment: Hi XenoPuTtSs, thank you kindly for your solution, it had me thinking about what I need to do about that string, since at times it is Cell, other times it is Cell Phone Number, so before trying to obtain the values, I tried to get as much variances as possible, then I run a method that will replace  certain things, for example I replace the colon with a space, Cell Phone Number with Cell etc.Then I use your coding as a base line to get everything I need. Thank you so much for your help and answer, I know the question was not straight forward and appreciate you understanding and taking the time

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
int start = myString.IndexOf("Name") + "Name : ".Length;
int len = myString.IndexOf("Cell") - start;

string res = myString.Substring(start, len);
```

Alternativly via Regex:

```
Regex r = new Regex("Name(.*)Cell");
string res = r.Matches[0].Value;
```

Comment: He'd better hope he never gets an email from Dave Cellington. Recommend using LastIndexOf instead of IndexOf

Comment: hehehe,  Well, we can all agree that the input string is poor.  We also don't know if Cell is always the second field.

Comment: @XenoPuTtSs of course this code is based on the input from the OP

Comment: Based on the input from the OP, the code to get the first name is:

var fullName = "Testy Von Test";

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, I understand that the input string is simply horrible, and to make this work has been a bit of a nightmare. Thank you kindly for your help, I really sincerely appreciate you taking the time to assist me.

Answer (score 0):

Is your mail body always in the exact format?

You can for instance do as shown in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zbgyrLpc/).

```
var mailbody = 'Name : Testy Von Test Cell 1111111111 email testy@testy';
var nameregex = /Name(.+?)Cell/
var match = nameregex.exec(mailbody);
console.log(match[1]); // Outputs " : Testy Von Test "
```

In your example it would capture, as seen in the console input, " : Testy von test ". And you can then manipulate it however you'd like. You can also modify the regex with additional options, depending on how your mail outputs vary.

```
var mailbody = 'Name : Testy Von Test Cell 1111111111 email testy@testy';
var nameregex = /Name\s:\s(.+?)\sCell/
var match = nameregex.exec(mailbody);
console.log(match[1]); // Outputs "Testy Von Test"
```

Comment: Hi Robin, thank you very much for taking the time to assist me in my question, I understand that the question is vague and there are too many variables to consider, and appreciate your input and assistance sincerely. Since there will be no guarantee that the format will always be the same I have decided to use the one XenoPuTtSs suggested, I do a bit of cleaning up on my string and then from there use the sub strings. I am still working on my solid solution (^^,). But thank you for your help, it was valuable and much appreciated.